# How to override the collection element type in subclass in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

For example, a Tiger is a Cat, but Tiger won't have any Cat child:

```
@Entity
class Cat {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Cat.class)
    Set<Cat> getChildren() { ... }
}
```

And the Tiger:

```
@Entity
class Tiger extends Cat {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Tiger.class)
    Set<Cat> getChildren() { ... }
}
```

The problem is, Hibernate won't allow such definition, as error:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.bee32.plover.orm.Tiger column: parent (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Any idea?

Comment: You need to decide how should it look in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it by providing a XML file (root element: ...), but why do you need it in the first place?

Normally, you would restrict the Tiger class to only accept children of the same class, so `getChildren()` would return a set of tigers.

In the database you'd have a discriminator defining the entity class of the dataset anyways. So if you assign a dataset with discriminator "CAT" (or similar) as the child of a "TIGER" you'd get an exception when loading the association anyways (since the entity would be of class `Cat` and can't be cast to `Tiger`).